# Chrome print dialog not showing or src failure

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, printing, src

I want to print a different content from my web page that includes an image. So is my JavaScript code:

```
function print() {
 var w = window.open();  
 w.document.write(....);  
    //  time for rendering images
 setTimeout(function () { w.print();  w.close();},10);
}
```

[Google Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) shows a new tab, with no print dialog. When I exit the tab and return it, the print dialog shows!

When I take out the 10 ms timeout, it not shows my image (there is no time for rendering the image), but the dialog shows instantly.

Maybe, someone will tell me: Creates HTML using DOM functions like `createElement` and `appendChild`. So you don't need rendering time and it is neater.

Therefore I did an alternative with whole HTML content created from scratch

I've used the `src` dinamic assigment for my image

```
ele.setAttribute("src","LogoUp.png"); // ele is an image element
```

instead using a static HTML with **same src value**

```
<img id="header" style="margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;" src="LogoUp.png" >
```

PS: *My Chrome is updated (v.63)*

Now there is no need for rendering time and I can extract the `setTimeout` function call, however the image is not loading. It's very weird. I saw it in the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), the  official Chrome debugger tool. It shows a right string, but no image is pointed.

I'm using a local computer with Windows 7 and the image is in the same directory as the html source.

So I'm crazy ...

**Update**:
I also have tried, with no success: (I also saw the html in `Chrome DevTools` )

```
 c.appendChild(document.getElementById("header").cloneNode(true))
// where c is the image's parent element
```

It's amazing because the original image works, when using `innerHTML`

Comment: Given what I see from your new HTML, you are missing a " quote that ends your style attribute, so it should be this: `<img  style="margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;" src="LogoUp.png" >`

Answer (score 0):

I've made more research and I've discovered a great solution without the need for a popup tab. The magic was made by `iFrame`. An empty one:

```
<iframe id="luck" style="border:none;" >
</iframe>
```

In other point, I've placed the content to be printed (with images)

```
<div class="printer" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:none"> 
...
</div>
```

Display is set with "none" (since I don't want to display that content on the page).

The print code is below in just 2 lines (long ones):

```
function procPrint() {
  document.getElementById("luck").contentDocument.body.innerHTML =    
    document.getElementsByClassName('printer')[0].innerHTML;
  setTimeout(function() {luck.contentWindow.print();},10); 
   // just 10 ms waiting time is enough, 
   //  maybe complex content demands more.
}
```

**Advantages:**

- No popup. `Cancel` or `OK` resumes the original page.
- Print dialog is not missing. No tab to be changed.

**Disadvantages:**

- Rendering of innerHTML assignment demands `setTimeout` use.
- `Firefox` does not give an error, but the printing does not work. My goal is just a prototype. So for me, I'm ok.

-/-

I did not testing the `src` bug (correct string don't display the image) with DOM assignments.

I'm satisfied with what I got. I hope it will be useful for someone.

**Update:**

I've discovered that `iFrame` printing ignores completely CSS resources like a printing CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/print.css" media="print" />
```

or `@media print` specs inside a CSS file like:

```
@media print {
   body { font-size: 14pt }
}
```

It occurs because logically the frame is another document. So the style needs to be attached in the HTML that will be cloned inside `iFrame` or it's possible includes css file dinamically in the child after cloning HTML inside the `iFrame` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)).

My brain understand the logic, but it's weird: If you puts a style in the HTML printing source it works, but if you use the class name in the CSS file, it changes the clone source but not in the cloned nodes.

If one needs to change or set the background color (or image) in the printing, changes directly in the body iframe. One specifies background color in the cointaner doesn't make the work.

In this case, add the below line in `procPrint` function above.

```
d.style.backgroundColor  = "#FF0000";
```

**Update 2**
For invisible `iFrame` on the screen uses:

```
@media screen{    
    .printonly, .printonly *  {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```